# Can't display voxel data using Open3D

Tags: jupyter-notebook, 3d, generative-adversarial-network, data-preprocessing, open3d

I wanted to display a single object from the Princeton 3DShapeNet dataset using Open3D. I loaded the voxels from the sample matlab file and managed to display it using matplotlib.
I also want to display the sample object (an airplane) in Open3D, by using the o3d VoxelGrid.

However, I get following error:
`AttributeError: 'open3d.cuda.pybind.geometry.VoxelGrid' object has no attribute 'voxels'`

This the code block from the notebook:

```python
voxels = scipy.io.loadmat("3DShapeNets/volumetric_data/airplane/30/test/e5bf09ef0e8de9e8a9de7e2f11b2d506_9.mat")["instance"]
voxels = np.pad(voxels, (1, 1), "constant", constant_values=(0, 0))
voxels = scipy.ndimage.zoom(voxels, (2, 2, 2), mode="constant", order=0)

def PlotVoxels(voxels):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(projection = '3d')

    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.voxels(voxels, edgecolor="blue")

    plt.show()

def PlotVoxels3D(voxels):
    voxel_grid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid()
    voxel_grid.voxels = o3d.utility.Vector3iVector(np.argwhere(voxels))

    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([voxel_grid])
    
PlotVoxels(voxels)
PlotVoxels3D(voxels)
```

Comment: Can you upload the voxel `.mat` file

Comment: I agree the .mat file could be helpful in debugging. Does it throw the same error with a simpler voxel setup (e.g. if you voxelise a [sample point cloud](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/data/index.html#demoicppointclouds)) ?

The error seems to hint that the CUDA bindings for this functionality have not been built. My questions to help pin point the issue would be: What OS (and version) are you using ? What version of Open3D are you using ? (Is it compiled from source, if so, with CUDA bindings ? and what version of CUDA) ?

Comment: ...I ask because sometimes there may be a mismatch between online docs and current source code (sometimes a pybind exposed property or method may be renamed or removed). For example, in the older version of open3d I use (0.16.1) `voxels` is not part of `VoxelGrid` (I get the same error you get except it's `open3d.cpu.pybind.geometry.VoxelGrid`. One workaround I can think of is to convert to write your voxel data as a .ply pointcloud to load via `open3d_io.read_voxel_grid`.